# PySpark minimum of a list

Tags: pyspark

How to find a minimum of a list that is stored in a cell?
I can do a udf, but it feels like an overkill. The `min` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` works only on groups (that is the result of groupBy).

```
min_ = udf(lambda inarr: min(inarr), IntegerType())
myDataFrameWithMin = myDataFrame.withColumn('min_value', min_(F.col('position_list')))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you imported `pyspark.sql.functions` and python's `min` is covered, you can still access it with `__builtins__` prefix, for example:

```
min_ = udf(lambda inarr: __builtins__.min(inarr), IntegerType())
```

Comment: is there a way to not use udfs at all?

Answer (score 0):

Just sort and then take the first value/row.

```
df.sort(col, ascending=True)
```